# How to update many rows with uniqid() making them unique in php

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, unique

I created a new column in mysql, that is going to store a unique value for all of the elements inside the database.

Now I would like to populate all rows with this unique value using `uniqid()`.

But since the function makes use of `microtime()`, I can't update all rows together.

How could I do it?

```
$unique_id = uniqid();

$sql = "UPDATE posts SET unique_id = :unique_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['unique_id' => $unique_id]);
```

This code updates the same value for all rows.
How can every row be unique?

Comment: What do you mean? can you share your code? uniqid() function can be used to generate an absolute unique value based on current timestamp and you can add entropy to lower even more the chances that the timestamps match (literally happen at the same milisecond which is impossible)

Comment: You are using above code and get actual duplicates on uniqid?

Comment: @pr1nc3 Yes, test it. I was thinking about the possibility of calling the function with a delay of, let's say 1 second, in a foreach loop. But I do not know how to develop the code

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  posts 
SET unique_id = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: This works, updating random unique values to my posts, but I wanted each post to have a 13 characters random value, as uniqid() produces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
update posts set unique_id = @i:=@i+1 order by rand();
```

The numbers will now randomly assigned to rows, but each row has a unique value.

Comment: I need each post to have a 13 characters long unique id, as uniqid() produces.

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqid('', TRUE),
```

You can use uniqid with the entropy to make it more sensitive in time to narrow down even more the chance of duplicates but keep one thing in mind:

> This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since
>   most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is
>   changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does
>   not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to
>   increase likelihood of uniqueness.

What you can do as well is to put a random prefix like:

`uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE);`

That will eliminate every chance to generate a duplicate.

You are going to use a random prefix + entropy sensitivity. The generated value will be unique even if your script runs that fast that the timestamp happens to be the same even in miliseconds.

The problem with your code is that you use `uniqid()` function one time by assigning it to a variable and from there you get duplicates of course cause you use this variable:

Try this code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET unique_id = uuid()";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I set $unique_id variable as you hinted me but I still get the same exact value for each row. Missing something...

Comment: Ok I tried it as above but I still get the same value

Comment: Can you try once more? Edited my answer

Comment: It's working with uuid() put in the sql variable but I don't get why the same won't update with uniqid().

Comment: I have added an explanation for you in my answer. It's not a uniqid issue, it's that you are using it only once. So you generate only 1 value and update everything with it. That's why you get duplicates. Since you don't have a loop or something to trigger it more times so you generate more than 1 values use the mysql approach and solve it like that. There is no reason to use php when you can do it straight in your query. If you think my answer helped you solve your issue please don't forget to accept it for future users to see it as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm stubborn lol. I was not satisfacted of the result because I wanted the unique value to be the product of uniqid() instead of uuid(), so I found my own way, thanks for helping though

Comment: Fair enough, if you found a solution to it that means you found something that can be looped over.  If it works for you it's more than fine :) The goal is to solve your issue after all

Answer (score 0):

So after some tries I came across my own solution, using uniqid().
Here's my code, commented:

```
// Selecting all the posts
$sql = "SELECT id, pro_key FROM posts";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$posts = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Looping through all the results and updating them one by one with a delay of 1 second between the updates
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $sql = "UPDATE posts SET unique_id = :unique_id WHERE id = :id";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['id' => $post->id, 'unique_id' => uniqid()]);
  // delay
  sleep(1);
}
```

Hope this helps.